# Синхронизация папок

Tags: c#

Хочу уточнить алгоритм работы, перед тем как писать прогу.

Есть две папки. Если второй нет, то создать. В первой папке лежат файлы. Если во второй файлов нет, скопировать в неё содержимое первой. Далее в реальном времени смотреть время изменения файлов первой папки. Если в первой папке содержимое "свежее", чем во второй, скопировать из первой во вторую.

Есть код для txt файлов (см код. снизу). Как мне выгрузить весь каталог с 1 папки и сравнить как я сравнивал в коде. Если есть советы, можете дописать код? Любая помощь сойдет, буду очень признателен.

```
FileInfo q = new FileInfo(@"1\1.txt");
FileInfo w = new FileInfo(@"2\2.txt");
DateTimeOffset a = q.LastWriteTime;
DateTimeOffset b = w.LastWriteTime;
if (a < b)
{
    w.Delete();
    q.CopyTo(@"2\2.txt");
}
if (q.Exists == false)
{
    q.Delete();
    w.CopyTo(@"1\1.txt");
}
```

Comment: Для мониторинга в реальном времени используйте класс [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал на скорую руку, надеюсь у Вас получиться отрефакторить код.

```
Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> dict_files_1 = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();            

string[] array_files_1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TEST\1");

foreach(string path in array_files_1)
{
   FileInfo f_info = new FileInfo(path);
   string[] array = path.Split('\\');
   string filename = array[array.Length - 1];
   dict_files_1.Add(filename, f_info.LastWriteTime);
}   

if(!File.Exists(@"D:\TEST\2"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\TEST\2");
}

string[] array_files_2 = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\TEST\2");

if(array_files_2.Length == 0)
{
    foreach(string path in array_files_1)
    {
        string[] array = path.Split('\\');
        string filename = array[array.Length - 1];
        File.Copy(path, @"D:\TEST\2\" + filename);
    }
 }
 else
 {
     foreach(string path in array_files_2)
     {
         FileInfo f_info = new FileInfo(path);
         string[] array = path.Split('\\');
         string filename = array[array.Length - 1];
         if(!dict_files_1.ContainsKey(filename))
         {                        
             f_info.CopyTo(@"D:\TEST\2\" + filename);
         }
         else
         {
             DateTimeOffset dt = dict_files_1[filename];
             if(dt > f_info.LastWriteTime)
             {
                 File.Delete(@"D:\TEST\2\" + filename);
                 f_info.CopyTo(@"D:\TEST\2\" + filename);
             }
          }
     }              
 }
```